# Conditional sum across multiple columns

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have columns A, B, C, E and I want to sum the numbers in E (range of rows) only if the value in E is not empty and matches a value in either A or B or C of the corresponding row. For example, in the sample below, A4=E4 and B7=E7, so we sum E4 + E7.

[image]

The only way I know how to solve this is to use two separate operations; a conditional if function which outputs matching values to another column and then a summation function to sum the entire column. I'd like to solve this with a single operation if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUM(FILTER(E1:E9, 
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&A1:A9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&B1:B9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&C1:C9*1)))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(" "&TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C9),,999^99)))&" ", " "&E1:E9&" "), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(" "&TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C9),,999^99)))&" ", " "&F1:F9&" ")))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: If I wanted to extend the use case further to have another column F, where there is either a value in E or F (but not both) that could potentially match A-C, and we should sum matching cells from E and F?

I tried the following:
`=SUM(FILTER(E1:E9, 
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&A1:A9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&B1:B9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&C1:C9*1)))+
SUM(FILTER(F1:F9, 
 REGEXMATCH(""&F1:F9, ""&A1:A9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&F1:F9, ""&B1:B9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&F1:F9, ""&C1:C9*1)))`

But this seems to sum everything from F regardless of whether it matches.

Comment: `=SUM(FILTER(E1:E9, 
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&A1:A9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&B1:B9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&E1:E9, ""&C1:C9*1)), 
 FILTER(F1:F9, 
 REGEXMATCH(""&F1:F9, ""&A1:A9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&F1:F9, ""&B1:B9*1)+
 REGEXMATCH(""&F1:F9, ""&C1:C9*1)))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TDPu.png

Comment: The above formula seems to misbehave for the following scenarios. Taking your latest provided example but changing E4=10 (so that it does not match any of A4,B4,C4), gives me sum of 13. Additionally if I change E4 to any value less 10, then sum is #N/A. Any ideas?

Comment: Last question, if I want to add support for decimal values with scale=1? Thanks!

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(1*IFERROR(
 REGEXEXTRACT(" "&TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C9),,999^99)))&" ", " "&TO_TEXT(E1:E9)&" "), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(" "&TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C9),,999^99)))&" ", " "&TO_TEXT(F1:F9)&" ")))))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9gbD.png